# Error in reading GZip in java but not in python

Tags: java, gzip

I write some data to GZIP binary file using the below java code

```
    public static void WriteDictAndIndex(HashMap<String, Term> terms, int index){

        try{
            GZIPOutputStream postingListOutput = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(String.format("./generated/posting_list_%d", index)));
            GZIPOutputStream dictionaryOutput = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(String.format("./generated/dictionary_%d", index)));
            Integer START=0, SIZE=0, VOCAB=0;
            for(String s : terms.keySet()){
                ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Byte>> postingList = terms.get(s).postingList;
                SIZE = postingList.size()*5;

                // Write one posting list to the file system
                ByteBuffer list_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(SIZE);
                int totalCount = 0;
                for(Pair<Integer, Byte> p : postingList) {
                    // Write the docID (4 bytes)
                    list_buffer.putInt(p.getValue0()); 
                    // Write the term frequency (1 byte)
                    byte termFrequency = p.getValue1();
                    list_buffer.put(termFrequency);
                    // Counter for the total occurrences of words
                    totalCount += (int)termFrequency;
                }
                if(index == 0 && totalCount == 1)
                    continue;
                postingListOutput.write(list_buffer.array());

                // Write one dictionary entry to the file system
                byte[] token = s.getBytes();
                ByteBuffer dict_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(16+token.length);
                dict_buffer.putInt(token.length);
                dict_buffer.put(token);
                dict_buffer.putInt(terms.get(s).documentFrequency);
                dict_buffer.putInt(START);
                dict_buffer.putInt(SIZE);
                dictionaryOutput.write(dict_buffer.array());

                START += SIZE;
                VOCAB += 1;
            }
            //INFO
            System.out.println(String.format("Vocabulary Size: %d", VOCAB));
            postingListOutput.close();
            dictionaryOutput.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Now when I read first 695 bytes of this file using python, it reads as expected. But when I read the file using java GZIP, there are some discrepancies (the last 10 bytes of the first 695 bytes that I read are different)

I am trying to read using the following code:

```
try{
            GZIPInputStream postingList = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(args[1])));
            GZIPInputStream dictionary = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(args[2])));
            byte[] buf = new byte[4];
            while(true){
                // Get the size of the token from the dictionary
                dictionary.read(buf);
                int tokenSize = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getInt();

                // Read the token
                byte[] tokenBuffer = new byte[tokenSize];
                dictionary.read(tokenBuffer);
                String token = new String(tokenBuffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                
                // Read the document frequency
                dictionary.read(buf);
                int documentFrequency = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getInt();

                // Read the starting index of the posting list
                dictionary.read(buf);
                int START = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getInt();

                // Read the size of the posting list
                dictionary.read(buf);
                int SIZE = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf).getInt();

                // Read the posting list
                
                for(int i=0; i<documentFrequency; i++){
                    byte[] ID = new byte[4];
                    postingList.read(ID);
                    int docID = ByteBuffer.wrap(ID).getInt();

                    byte[] frequency = new byte[1];
                    postingList.read(frequency);
                    System.out.println(String.format("%d: %d: %d",i, docID, frequency[0]));
                }
                break;
            }
            postingList.close();
            dictionary.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
```

The print statement above will print multiple lines with after reading an integer(4 byte) and a byte in each line.
Last 2 print statments should be of the form(which python reads fine)
137: 81257: 1
138: 81737: 1
But I am getting(using the below java code)
137: 65536: 61
138: 1761673217: 63

Any pointers on what could be the mistake?

Comment: 65536 is suspicious. This is an exact power of 2 (e.g. 2^16). I would therefore check if you reading and writing offsets / lengths actually align.

It does not really sound GZip related to me (juste remove GZip compression and check).

Comment: @GPI I am writing 5 bytes at a time to the binary for 139 times. I printed out the byte value and the discrepancy I found is that python is reading the sequence {{0 1 59 219 1} {0 1 61 105 1} } which is right but java has 2 extra zeros and I don't know how they creeped in. {{0 1 59 219 1} {0 1 **0 0** 61 105 1}

Comment: I found the problem. I allocated 4 bytes (assuming it will read 4 since input stream has them) when reading but java actually read only 2 even though there were thousands of bytes ahead. I just needed to synchronize the reading with the byte alignment.

Comment: Always *always*  **always** check the value returned by `stream.read()` method :-). newer java versions (I think 9+) provide `readExactly` methods that make it easier, but you will always have corner cases (e.g. you want to read exactly 4 bytes, but there are only 3 left).

Comment: I meant `readNBytes` and not `readExactly` ^^